# size of array of structs in bytes

Tags: c#

i have an array of structs and i need to get the size of it in bytes

in C++ i can make it using sizeof()

but i need it C#

thnx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)) * array.Length`

Comment: multiplied by arr.Length ? ;-)

Comment: I didn't got it. Let's say I have `public fixed Byte smthng[12];`. If I write e.g. `int a = smthng.Lenght;` it triggers a compiler error. Neither worked `sizeof()`. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: That's not an "array" in the .NET sense, that's a "fixed-size array".

Comment: Ah. Okay. So how do I get it's size?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: You need to use reflection. `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(YourType).GetField("smthng").FieldType)`

Comment: @Mehrdad wow, what a giant construction…! Probably then would be better just to declare somewhere a constant variable, that going to hold the size :D

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Yeah, I was assuming you didn't have that option.

Comment: @Mehrdad how could that be?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: I don't know, I didn't think about it too much.

Answer (score 5):

There is the `sizeof` operator. However, it can only be used in unsafe context.

There is also a difference to the method proposed in the other answer, namingly:

> For all other types, including structs, the sizeof operator can be used only in unsafe code blocks. Although you can use the Marshal.SizeOf method, the value returned by this method is not always the same as the value returned by sizeof. Marshal.SizeOf returns the size after the type has been marshaled, whereas sizeof returns the size as it has been allocated by the common language runtime, including any padding.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf(v=VS.100).aspx)

Example:

```
unsafe
{
  int size = sizeof(MyStruct)*myArray.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Buffer.ByteLength(Array)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.bytelength?view=net-6.0) will do exactly what you want.